# 502 Bad Gateway after AMI Image creation from EC2 running Flask using Docker Compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, load-balancing, amazon-rds

Also my application serve NPM React app as well as Flask backend with RDS attached. It is running Dualstack.
I was able to track down that my website went 502 bad gateway. A minute after I created AMI image to copy Ec2 instance to my other account. For now I deployed the Instance and tried running(not running yet).

Cloud Trail log of AMI create

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "",
        "arn": "",
        "accountId": "",
        "accessKeyId": "",
        "userName": "",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {},
            "webIdFederationData": {},
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
                "creationDate": "2019-09-13T02:30:45Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2019-09-13T04:30:01Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateImage",
    "awsRegion": "ap-southeast-2",
    "sourceIPAddress": "***.66.79.65",
    "userAgent": "console.ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "instanceId": "****05818a11a690e",
        "name": "devport",
        "description": "Port to Developer version of new one",
        "noReboot": false,
        "blockDeviceMapping": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "deviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                    "ebs": {
                        "volumeSize": 20,
                        "deleteOnTermination": true,
                        "volumeType": "gp2",
                        "encrypted": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "requestId": "******-3cfb-49d0-917f-78641a0561cc",
        "imageId": "ami-*****bfa644e5a043"
    },
    "requestID": "*****-3cfb-49d0-917f-78641a0561cc",
    "eventID": "******-7780-4d61-900b-607378d7dc88",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating AMI from instance it has two option either reboot during the creation of AMI or either do it the fly but the second one is not recommended.

[image]

So if you did not check the 502 bad gateway is expected until you restart your container if it did not restart automatically.

You can only [share AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html) when its ready state.
[image]
So at step 4 it reboot the instance and after step 5 it ready to share.

**noReboot (Boolean)**

> By default this property is set to false, which means Amazon EC2
>   attempts to cleanly shut down the instance before image creation and
>   reboots the instance afterwards. When set to true, Amazon EC2 does not
>   shut down the instance before creating the image. When this option is
>   used, file system integrity on the created image cannot be guaranteed.
>   Default is FALSE.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. "noReboot": false in Trail log. means I didn't checked the Reboot. so After the Image creating and lanching Instance from AMI. I have rebooted the instance that icopied from. But Its is still 502. Is there any other way to reboot it to working state.

Comment: 502 bad gateway mean backend is not responding, did you check your container is running? if running is the port healthy?

Comment: it is running and its healthy. My entire ec2 was deployed as Terraform template and i copied AMI. is that something messing up. Sorry if its too naive.

Comment: Yes AMI can mess sometimes, For docker container you better to use ECS optimized AMI instead of your own. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html

Comment: Thanks mate. that helps. But I am stil struck re starting containers. This is the current situation. https://i.imgur.com/HQaFYgB.png backend_mc is the flask container. still 502 bad gateway.

Comment: I saw docker not running. so i started it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199551/discussion-between-adiii-and-arun-k).

Comment: I found my Nginx service got stopped after reboot. I restarted it its all good. THanks for the help mate.

Comment: you can add nginx in initd/boot time to start automatically to avoid such thing in future :)